# What can I say about the quotient group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group of order $24$, and let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $6$. 
So the quotient group $ {G\over H} $ is Abelian group?. What can I say about the quotient group beside her order?

Comment: Any group of order $p^2$ is abelian, where $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

The quotient group has order $24/6=4$.
An abelian group of order $4$ is either $C_4$ or $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: How can you tell that this quotient group is Abelian??

Comment: Every group of order $\le 5$ is abelian. Try to prove this, its a great exercise. In particular, $S_3$ of order $6$ is the smallest nonabelian group.

Comment: haha thanks
that was much easier then i thought

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is a group of order $24$, and $H$ is a normal subgroup of order $6$. As such, $G/H$ is of order $4$. The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups tells you that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}_4$ or $\mathbf{Z}_2 \times \mathbf{Z}_2$. (Note that each individual part is of prime power order, if you had an abelian group of order $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$, then $\mathbf{Z}_4 \times \mathbf{Z}_3$ would be an alternative for isomorphism, while $\mathbf{Z}_6 \times \mathbf{Z}_2$ would not.)

Comment: Using the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups is overkill.

Comment: Well, that theorem is the very basis of your own answer; you simply didn't mention it.